# Origin and destination point is not placed precisely on Google Maps SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-directions-api

I tried to draw a route with Google Maps on iOS that come from Google Direction API.
I hit this end point

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving&key=%@", origin, destination, gDirectionKey];
```

Then I got its routes that I draw with `GMSPolyline`

```
GMSPath *path =[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:resultData[@"routes"][0][@"overview_polyline"][@"points"]];
if (routeToCustomer == nil)
    routeToCustomer = [[GMSPolyline alloc] init];
routeToCustomer.path = path;
routeToCustomer.strokeWidth = 7;
routeToCustomer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:ACTIVE_COLOR];
routeToCustomer.map = _mapView;
```

It looks like that the starting line doesn't start in its coordinate, but in the nearest way. See image below.

[image: google direction]

Is it possible to draw line from its coordinate into "starting direction"? If so, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can draw a polyline between starting line coordinate & actual starting point!!

Comment: what do mean by "starting direction"?

Comment: Starting direction is starting point from google direction result. Actual starting point is my initial point that I use as parameter to google direction API

Answer (score 0):

You will need draw a polyline from starting point of google direction result and actual starting point in mapView.

```
GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(actualLat,actualLon)];
[path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLat,startLon)];
GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
```